# Playing a stream by my discord bot on heroku doesnt work

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I want to make a Bot, that plays a livestream of an online radio. I use Discord JS v13.
On Heroku I have installed the following buildpacks:

- heroku/nodejs
- https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
- https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git
- https://github.com/OnlyNoob/heroku-buildpack-libsodium.git

My code is the following:

```
let voiceChn = message.member.voice.channel;
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: message.member.voice.channel.guildId,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    selfDeaf: true
  });
const player = createAudioPlayer();
let resource = createAudioResource(STREAM_URL);
connection.subscribe(player);
  connection.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, () => {
    player.play(resource);
});
```

It does work running on my pc but it does not run on Heroku.
These are the packages I have installed:

- "@discordjs/opus": "^0.5.3"
- "@discordjs/rest": "^0.5.0"
- "@discordjs/voice": "^0.10.0"
- "discord-api-types": "^0.36.0"
- "discord.js": "^13.8.1"
- "ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.1"
- "libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.10"

I do get the following error: The player immediately emits the idle event and thats logged:

```
{
status: 'playing',
missedFrames: 0,
playbackDuration: 120,
resource: AudioResource {
    playStream: OggDemuxer {
    _readableState: [ReadableState],
    _events: [Object: null prototype],
    _eventsCount: 5,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: [WritableState],
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _remainder: null,
    _head: null,
    _bitstream: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
},
    edges: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    metadata: null,
    volume: undefined,
    encoder: undefined,
    audioPlayer: undefined,
    playbackDuration: 0,
    started: true,
    silencePaddingFrames: 5,
    silenceRemaining: 0
},
onStreamError: [Function: onStreamError]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error, but I believe I had the same problem and fixed it.
Didn't test if all the changes are needed, but here goes:

- Instead of your heroku-buildpack-libsodium package, I use:
  https://github.com/Crazycatz00/heroku-buildpack-libopus
- Changed every URLs 'https' with 'http'
- Use a DNS lookup tool to change domain name with IPV4 form

  `'https://stream.skymedia.ee/live/NRJdnb'  becomes  'http://185.31.240.229:8888/NRJdnb'`
- Deploy slash commands after you change their code